# Visual Composer's Page Builder on custom field in a custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-fields, visual-composer

we've inherited a wp site with custom post types.

the custom post types each have a custom field of type 'textarea'. (in other words they dont use the wp post_content field)

we are trying to figure out how to use Visual Composer for the contents of these fields.

so we wouldnt need Visual Composer's page builder on 2 elements - only on the one, the custom field.

anyone know if/how one could do this?

thanks in advance,
vauneen

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin that will help you accomplish this.

I know [WP ACF-VC Bridge](https://codecanyon.net/item/wp-acfvc-bridge-integrates-advanced-custom-fields-and-visual-composer-wordpress-plugins/19622052).

With this plugin you can create custom field of type 'Visual Composer'.

Comment: Thank you for this. I did read about this plugin and it looks great. 
But we have existing custom fields that we cant change. so we need to see if we can add the PageBuilder to existing custom fields in custom post types. thanks again for your response though, V